# scala Functonal abstraction (List) not working

Tags: scala, functional-programming

please help me out in this scala throwing an error in below context

```
def SelectValues(list: List[Int],sel:Int => Boolean) ={
      var sum =0
      list.foreach{ e =>
        if(sel(e)) sum += e
      }
      sum
      println(sum)
    }

    println(SelectValues(List(1,2){e => true}))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq0Tr.png)'screen shot

Comment: The error has been found, you could consider implementing your function in more functional style: `def SelectValues(list: List[Int], sel:Int => Boolean) = list.filter(sel).reduce(_+_)`

Comment: `list.filter(sel).sum`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your println line:

```
println(SelectValues(List(1,2){e => true}))
```

You don't have a comma between the List(1,2) and the {e => true} this means that you are sending a single parameter to SelectValues:

```
List(1,2){e => true}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
List(1,2)(f)
```

where f is the function. i.e. you are trying to call a function (apply in this case) on the resulting object from List(1,2) and not sending the second parameter (sel)).

the compiler analyzes first the SelectValues signature (before figuring out what your object is) and sees only one parameter.

To solve this, simply add the missing comma:

```
println(SelectValues(List(1,2), {e => true}))
```

Comment: @Sekhar if this solves the issue, you should consider accepting the answer. (pressing the V below the votes). Otherwise, the question remains active for other people to try to answer.